# Get value to columns from another columns automatic

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Users:

```
UserID | UserName
--------------
1        Jack
2        Evelin
```

Shop:

```
ShopID | ShopName | ShopUserID
-------------------------------
1        Prague     1
2        Berlin     2
```

Is possible get automatically update table:

```
ShopID | ShopName | ShopUserID
-------------------------------
1        Prague     Jack
2        Berlin     Evelin
```

Can I use trigger?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get the desired result while selecting also, why to replace numeric ids with string values. Trigger only works when you add/edit/delete if you want to update the entire table then you will need to run one update query.

Comment: yes when you update/add/delete you could create trigger to update the third table.

Comment: you can use a stored procedure...

Comment: do you need an example implementation or just a simple yes is enough?

Comment: @Vance If you could , yes please

Answer (score 0):

Please use Join please try this query :

```
Select s.shopID,s.ShopName,u.UserName from Shop as s Left Join Users as u on s.ShopUserID = u.UserID
```

Output will look like this :

```
ShopID | ShopName | UserName
-------------------------------
1        Prague     Jack
2        Berlin     Evelin
```